# Overworked "talaq" tag: talaq (husband-initiated), khul' (wife-initiated), faskh (annulled), and civil divorce. What to do?

Tags: discussion, tag

There are 161 questions tagged [talaq](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talaq).  These include four topics:

1. talaq
2. khul' (wife-initiated divorce), e.g. [Is meher payable even after a divorce demanded by wife?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/602/17163)
3. faskh (an Islamic kind of marriage annulment) [Can a marriage be annulled in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36437/17163)
4. civil divorce (i.e., non-Islamic divorce), e.g., [May I remarry in islam before mutual legal divorce is final?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17168/17163), to a certain extent.

(There's also another form of husband-initiated divorce: the *"you are like my mother" divorce* ([Islam Q&A](http://zihaar)), or zihaar.)

And some talk about combinations of these kinds of divorce, e.g., [Can you get a civil divorce and stay islamically married?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29612/17163)

**Question**: What should we do to make this clearer?

I see a problem, in particular, with khul', faskh, and civil divorce not actually being considered forms of "talaq" (assuming I understand things correctly).  It seems, then, perhaps renaming this tag to "divorce" might be an option.  Maybe the community has some other ideas.

Comment: We should have three separate tags. The aspects each tag can be described with are who initiates the action, how the action is initiated, the rights of each party after the conclusion of the act, the conditions for remarrying or reuniting, and the legitimate causes.

Comment: @III-AK-III I think we should post answers.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly speaking I had the same idea not long ago, but came to the conclusion that many people don't know of these differences or prefer to choose the talaq tag.

Let me explain my point: Are we ready to check all the tags, and correct them, I mean it is annoying enough that we have users who by definition for what ever reason use the [islamic-scholar](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-scholar) in each post or use irrelevant tags.

The more tags we have the more tags we have to manage, the more posts we have to edit.

If necessary I'd say we can chose to split it into two tags, my suggestions could be:

- [talaq](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talaq) and [talaq-by-court](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talaq-by-court).
  In this case I'm rather sceptical whether people would understand the second option. But this would include khul', and faskh and maybe even civil divorce (it depends on how we would define these terms in the tag-wiki)
- [talaq](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talaq) and [civil-divorce](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-divorce)
  In this case most people would use the second tag only for non-shari'a conform divorces unless we define it in the tag-wiki.

There are certainly other similar new tag candidates (I have a lot of them in mind and I'm still checking whether it is worth discussing or creating them)

Answer (score 2):

Three tags may be warranted:

1. [talaq](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talaq)
2. [khul](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/khul)
3. [faskh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faskh)

The three words refer to the separation of a husband and a wife by terminating their marriage with an accompanied financial consequence.

[talaq](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talaq) is a termination of a marriage that can only be initiated by the husband by saying, writing, or otherwise indicating his intention to end their marriage. Talaq may be due to cause or may be out of convenience. The husband has the right to reinstigate the marriage within a period after the onset of the talaq (*'iddah*) without the need for a new marriage contract (and all its associated requirements). The remarriage is capped at a maximum of two times, after which a third divorce requires that the wife be lawfully married to another person prior to remarriage. The husband has to pay a financial compensation to the wife.

[khul](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/khul) is a termination of a marriage that is initiated by the wife and requires a judge to rule for the separation to take place. Khul's must have a valid reason (e.g., marriage not sustainable due to lack of compatibility, fear of not fulfilling duties of either spouse, etc.). The husband does not have the right to reinstigate the marriage except through a new marriage contract with all its associated requirements and conditions. The wife has to pay a financial compensation to the husband.

[faskh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faskh) is a termination of a marriage that is initiated by a judge and does not require approvals from either spouse. Faskh must have a valid cause (e.g., marriage not sustainable due to lack of compatibility, the apostasy of either spouse, embracing Islam by either spouse when an exemption is not allowed for the marriage to continue, adultery, cruelty, abandonment, etc.). The husband does not have the right to reinstigate the marriage except through a new marriage contract with all its associated requirements and conditions. The new marriage contract does not count as a second marriage, i.e., three incidents of [talaq](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talaq) are required for final separation.

As for [talaq-by-court](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talaq-by-court), it could be a synonom to both [khul](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/khul) and [faskh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faskh)(). If in the future, having two separate bins for [khul](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/khul) and [faskh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faskh) does not prove useful (either due to under-utilization of either bin, or due to ambiguity), then one of the moderators can combine both [khul](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/khul) and [faskh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faskh) under [talaq-by-court](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talaq-by-court)

The [civil-divorce](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-divorce) is covered by any of the tags above when done in a civil court in a Muslim-majority country or otherwise. I cannot think of a reason why it would not be covered by any of the three tags.